# XMPP client to connect gtalk server in android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to make an XMPP client to connect to a gtalk server in android.

I had succesfuly done it in java, and it works fine in java.

But when I try it on android, it throws an exception .

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration`

on the first line of my code where I am trying to configure the connection using smack `ConnectionConfiguration` class. I am also including the smack.jar file in lib folder and linked it corresponding build path too.

Is there any specific smack api for android which support xmpp connection and all as like smack in java?

In the same code samck api is there but it doesn’t work for me as I am trying it for several time with different smack apis (smackx , smack , smackx-debuge , smackx-jingle), and facing the same problem.